# How do you add an Active Directory user to SharePoint using WSS?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory, wss

Is it possible to introduce existing AD users into SharePoint using WSS?

If I create a new list item manually, and there is a User / People Picker field in the list, if I type a username in the field and submit, SP finds the user and adds it in as a SP user.

Why does that not work when adding new items through WSS? I cannot get WSS to recognize a user by username, email, or first name last name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to avoid messing with the SharePoint System Account user.

I called the AddUserToGroup method in the UserGroup service.

A byproduct of calling the above method is the addition of the user as a SharePoint user.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your System Account is probably not in the AD Domain, check the Application Pool for your SharePoint site and see whether it is running with a domain account.